# data-wal is being filled when syncing data to SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, wal

I have connected my device and accessed my applications data by going to `/data/data/my.package.name/databases`.

Here I can see files:

```
data
data-shm
data-wal
```

As I can understand these files are specific to android system itself, but they represent SQLite database and yet they are not mountable to SQLite reader?

I have this issue when data is being downloaded and stored to database, after some time `data-wal` starts to become extremely huge (from maybe 12MB to 7GB) and after sync finished it becomes almost empty again. Am I correct in saying that this is probably the issue with transactions (somewhere transaction is not being closed and is always opened and because of this reason `data-wal` is being filled with back-up data in case of a rollback)?

Answer (score 0):

The database consists of these three files. When opening `data`, the other two are automatically used when needed.

The `-wal` file contains all changes made to the database since the last checkpoint. To [prevent the `-wal` file from becoming too large](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#avoiding_excessively_large_wal_files), use smaller transactions so that SQLite is able to do checkpoints, or just disable WAL mode altogether during bulk writes.